# More simple math help in bash!

Tags: bash, syntax, math

In the same thread as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1850235/simple-math-statements-in-bash-in-a-for-loop), I am giving this another shot and ask SO to help address how I should take care of this problem. I'm writing a bash script which needs to perform the following:

1. I have a circle in `x` and `y` with radius `r`.
2. I specify `resolution` which is the distance between points I'm checking.
3. I need to loop over x and y (from -r to r) and check if the current (x,y) is in the circle, but I loop over discrete `i` and `j` instead.
4. Then `i` and `j` need to go from `-r/resolution` to `+r/resolution`.
5. In the loop, what will need to happen is `echo "some_text i*resolution j*resolution 15.95 cm"` (note lack of `$`'s because I'm clueless). This output is what I'm really looking for.

My best shot so far:

```
r=40.5
resolution=2.5
end=$(echo "scale=0;$r/$resolution") | bc

for (( i=-end; i<=end; i++ ));do
    for (( j=-end; j<=end; j++ ));do
        x=$(echo "scale=5;$i*$resolution") | bc
        y=$(echo "scale=5;$j*$resolution") | bc
        if (( x*x + y*y <= r*r ));then      <-- No, r*r will not work
            echo "some_text i*resolution j*resolution 15.95 cm"
        fi
    done
done
```

I've had just about enough with bash and may look into ksh like was suggested by someone in my last question, but if anyone knows a proper way to execute this, please let me know! What ever the solution to this, it will set my future temperament towards bash scripting for sure.

Comment: Thanks for any help; I'll be back in the morning few hours to update and respond.

Comment: ksh ? please... that's going from bad to worse. My opinion is that you are using the wrong tool. a shell is supposed to be used to run programs, not to do math.

Comment: I've had project leads insist everything had to be done in the shell before, because 'nobody knew perl'. 

Sometimes, you've just gotta make it work with the constraints you've been given. Even if those constraints aren't sane.

Comment: I usually walk the door, but that's just me... ;) I mean, there's a difference between a insane, motivated constraint, and an insane, unmotivated constraint. Having a complex system written in bash just because nobody knows something else it's 1) offensive to the intelligence of the "nobodies" 2) offensive to your intelligence (as you have to put a square peg in a round hole) 3) going to produce unmaintainable code, so the "nobodies" will not understand anything out of the mess

Comment: On the other hand, if you are asked, for example, to produce code in assembler, that would appear as an insane constraint, but that could have a motivated background (integration with previous code, timing issues). It's insane because uncommon, very demanding, difficult to test, and hard to do, but it's not unreasonable or unmotivated in that context. Human factors do exist, I agree, and must be kept into strong consideration, but it's always a matter of balance. A good manager should know when to evolve the technology of his team, otherwise it will keep him stuck in old technology.

Comment: If folk are insisting you use shell to do maths, I'd dig out dc.sed and say "what do you mean, you don't know sed"? http://sed.sourceforge.net/grabbag/scripts/dc.sed

Comment: This could lead to dropoffs ("I'm tired of this brontosaur company, I'm not keeping myself updated here"), burnout ("What the hell, it's a bunch of cr** anyway, who cares), interoperability ("those guys use SOAP... how can we use SOAP from bash??") and competition ("how could they go on the market so fast? we are doing the same and it is taking us 3 times more the time and the people?")

Comment: Oh wow, I've started a flamewar. I certainly agree that maths in the shell just isn't a sensible thing to be doing (and indeed, that perl really should be called in as soon as the script even starts to get complicated).
Would it help to mention that I'm no longer at that place?

Comment: No, it's not a flamewar. It's just my opinion, but I don't assume I'm right.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to include the pipe into bc in the $()'s. Instead of.

```
end=$(echo "scale=0;$r/$resolution") | bc
```

use

```
end=$(echo "scale=0;$r/$resolution" | bc)
```

should help a bit.

**EDIT** And here's a solution.

```
r=40.5
resolution=2.5
end=$(echo "scale=0;$r/$resolution" | bc)

for i in $(seq -${end} ${end}); do
    for j in $(seq -${end} ${end}); do
        x=$(echo "scale=5;$i*$resolution" | bc)
        y=$(echo "scale=5;$j*$resolution" | bc)

        check=$(echo "($x^2+$y^2)<=$r^2" | bc)    
        if [ ${check} -eq '1' ]; then
            iRes=$(echo "$i*$resolution" | bc)
            jRes=$(echo "$j*$resolution" | bc)      
            echo "some_text $iRes $jRes 15.95 cm"
        fi
    done
done
```

Comment: Adam, the final echo prints nothing but literally "some_text i*resolution j*resolution 15.95 cm"!

Comment: Correction added, though you may want to change the scale for the iRes / jRes equations depending on your requirements.

Comment: Thanks. On my Mac the use of seq had to be replaced with x=-end;x<end kind of thing. Also, the if statement should have [[ ... ]] instead of single brackets.

Comment: On Macs (and other BSDs?) there's the `jot` command which can be used instead of `seq`. The argument syntax is a little different.

Answer (score 1):

As already mentioned this problem is probably best solved using bc, awk, ksh or another scripting language.

**Pure Bash.** Simple problems which actually need floating point arithmetic sometimes can be transposed to some sort of fixed point arithmetic using only integers. The following solution simulates 2 decimal places after the decimal point.
There is no need for pipes and external processes inside the loops if this precision is sufficient.

```
factor=100                                      # 2 digits after the decimal point
r=4050                                          # the representation of 40.50
resolution=250                                  # the representation of  2.50
end=$(( (r/resolution)*factor ))                # correct the result of the division

for (( i=-end; i<=end; i+=factor )); do
    for (( j=-end; j<=end; j+=factor )); do
        x=$(( (i*resolution)/factor ))          # correct the result of the division
        y=$(( (j*resolution)/factor ))          # correct the result of the division 
        if [ $(( x*x + y*y )) -le $(( r*r )) ] ;then     # no correction needed
                        echo "$x $y ... "
        fi
    done
done

echo -e "resolution = $((resolution/factor)).$((resolution%factor))"
echo -e "r          = $((r/factor)).$((r%factor))"
```

Comment: The script I'm write actual relies on user specified units, so I suppose this actually could work quite well if I specify nanometers!

Answer (score 0):

you haven't heard of (g)awk ??. then you should go learn about it. It will benefit you for the long run. Translation of your bash script to awk.

```
awk 'BEGIN{
    r=40.5
    resol=2.5
    end = r/resol
    print end
    for (i=-end;i<=end;i++) {
        for( j=-end;j<=end;j++ ){
            x=sprintf("%.5d",i*resol)
            y=sprintf("%.5d",j*resol)
            if ( x*x + y*y <= r*r  ){
                print ".......blah blah ......"
            }
        }    
    }
}'
```

Answer (score 0):

It's looking more like a `bc` script than a Bash one any way, so here goes:

```
#!/usr/bin/bc -q
/* -q suppresses a welcome banner - GNU extension? */ 
r = 40.5
resolution = 2.5

scale = 0
end = r / resolution

scale = 5

for ( i = -end; i <= end; i++ ) {
    /* moved x outside the j loop since it only changes with i */
    x = i * resolution
    for ( j = -end; j <= end; j++ ) {
        y = j * resolution
        if ( x^2 * y^2 <= r^2 ) {
            /*
               the next few lines output on separate lines, the quote on 
               a line by itself causes a newline to be created in the output
               numeric output includes newlines automatically
               you can comment this out and uncomment the print statement
               to use it which is a GNU extension
            */
            /* */
            "some_text
"
            i * resolution
            j * resolution
            "15.95 cm
"
            /* */
            /* non-POSIX: 
            print "some_text ", i * resolution, " ", j * resolution, " 15.95 cm\n"
            */
        }
    }
}
quit
```